# Sorting by, which is better - hashmap, treemap, custom implementation

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap, treemap

I have an ArrayList of `Subjects` and they have parameter `Date`, I want to group them into sorted array (maybe not array, but still sorted structure) of `Day` objects, so every `Day` will have parameter `Date` and object will contain only subjects with this date. So the thing I wanna do is somehow group them by date and then get them. I saw implementations of grouping by using HashMap, but then I have grouped structure but not sorted, so after that I should convert this to ArrayList for example. Or maybe I should use TreeMap, which will do the same but give me back sorted structure, or maybe best way is simply write my own sorter which will get `ArrayList<Subject>` and return `ArrayList<Day>`. Also I can use `LinkedHashMap` which will work too

So now I have no idea what is better and what should I choose? Important thing is that most likely I will not put new values or delete values from structure, I will only get them.

UPD: If I use map then `Date` will be key and `Day` object will be value.

By saying "get them" I meant iterate through them.

All this I'm doing in order to fill my UI elements with this info so most likely I will not search something in my structure later

Comment: If you use a `Map`, what is the key, what is the value?

Comment: When you say 'get them' do you mean access by key (e.g. `Day`) or iterate of the Collection? I can't see why it'd need to be sorted except for the latter reason.

Comment: use TreeMap if you need sorting by date.

Comment: I don't undertand very well what you need.
Is it for the algorithm to fill your structure ? Or for searching ?

Comment: You ask what's best to sort, and then suggest `HashMap`, while acknowledging that it doesn't actually sort. Do you need it sorted? why not just dump everything in an `ArrayList` and then use the `sort(...)` method?

Comment: @cricket_007 , d.j.brown, Massimo, I added answers to question, but I think I will do like AdamSkywalker said - use TreeMap, but still I don't understand why it's better than other ways

Comment: Treemap and TreeSet  are ordered data structures. Hashmap and Arraylist have no specific ordering and require additional computation to do so

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think you are asking for, but hopefully my answer can help even if it's not exactly it:

1. fast lookup using a `Day` as the key
2. the result of that lookup should be sorted (i.e. multiple times of the same day are ordered)
3. the possibility to see all subjects sorted by their `Day`

Here's one option.  Use a `Map` that associates a `Day` to a sorted list of `Subjects`, so `Map<Day, List<Subject>>`.  Since you don't need to add to it, you can build your mapping at the start and then sort it before you do any lookups.  Here's an outline:

```
Map<Day, List<Subject>> buildMap(List<Subject> subjects) {
    Map<Day, List<Subject>> map = new HashMap<Day, List<Subject>>();
    // create a list of subjects for each day
    for (Subject subject : subjects) {
        if (!map.containsKey(subject.getDate().getDay())) {
            map.put(subject.getDate().getDay(), new ArrayList<Subject>());
        }
        map.get(subject.getDate().getDay()).add(subject);
    }

    // go through and sort everything now that you have grouped them
    for (Day day : map.keySet()) {
        Collections.sort(map.get(day));
    }

    return map;
}
```

If you also need to be able to 'get' every entry sorted throughout the map, you could maintain a sorted list of days.  Like so:

```
List<Day> buildSortedDaysList(Map<Day, List<Subject>> map) {
    List<Day> sortedDays = new ArrayList<Day>(map.keySet());
    // again, many ways to sort, but I assume Day implements Comparable
    Collections.sort(sortedDays);
    return sortedDays;
}
```

You could then wrap it in a class, of which I recommend you create a better name:

```
class SortedMapThing {
    Map<Day, List<Subject>> map;
    List<Day> orderedDays;

    SortedMapThing(List<Subject> subjects) {
        map = buildMap(subjects);
        orderedDays = buildSortedDaysList(map);
    }

    List<Subject> getSubject(Day day) {
        return map.get(day);
    }

    List<Subject> getAllSubjects() {
        List<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<Subject>();
        for (Day day : orderedDays) {
            subjects.addAll(map.get(day));
        }
        return subjects;
    }

}
```

This implementation puts the work up front and gives you efficient lookup speed.  If I misunderstood your question slightly, you should be able to adjust it accordingly.  If I misunderstood your question entirely...I will be sad.  Cheers!

Comment: Declaring a Map where the values are Lists / is a sin when [Multimap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap) exists.